# How to install Eigen library to IAR c/c++ compiler

Tags: c++, eigen, iar

is it possible to port Eigen, a C++ template library for linear algebra, to IAR workbench for ARM. I have tried to do this while but am getting following compile errors

`Error[Pe337]: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "__nounwind __iar_builtin_get_CONTROL" (declared at line 58 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.3\arm\inc\c\iccarm_builtin.h") C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.3\arm\CMSIS\Core\Include\cmsis_gcc.h 151`

This is the entire error I get when I use the preprocessors

```
__GNUC__
__arm__
```

if I dont use these preprocessors I get an error from a #error preprocessor
from the Eigen file Macros.h

"error Please tell me what is the equivalent of **attribute**((aligned(n))) for your compiler"

```
#if (defined __CUDACC__)
  #define EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(n) __align__(n)
#elif EIGEN_COMP_GNUC || EIGEN_COMP_PGI || EIGEN_COMP_IBM || EIGEN_COMP_ARM
  #define EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(n) __attribute__((aligned(n)))
#elif EIGEN_COMP_MSVC
  #define EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(n) __declspec(align(n))
#elif EIGEN_COMP_SUNCC
  // FIXME not sure about this one:
  #define EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(n) __attribute__((aligned(n)))
#else
  //#define EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(n) __declspec(align(n))
  #error Please tell me what is the equivalent of __attribute__((aligned(n))) for your compiler
#endif
```

I have it working for visual c++ but not IAR. All includes are added.

These errors change based on the preprocessors I use to try to configure Eigen. Is it possible to use Eigen with IAR?

Comment: The `__iar_builtin_get_CONTROL` function name sounds more like IAR issue than Eigen issue. (I don't know what Eigen is, so I may be wrong) Are you perhaps using IAR support headers that are for different version of IAR than what you are using?

Comment: I dont believe I am using the wrong support headers. I haven't changed anything there. How would I be sure though?  when I remove Eigen, everything works fine again.

Comment: What header file do you get this error from, and is that file part of Eigen? (In the future, please always include complete error messages in your posts)

Comment: I get it from file cmsis_gcc.h     which is not from Eigen                                                                                with error: Error[Pe337]: linkage specification is incompatible with previous "__nounwind __iar_builtin_get_CONTROL" (declared at line 58 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.3\arm\inc\c\iccarm_builtin.h") C:\Program Files (x86)\IAR Systems\Embedded Workbench 8.3\arm\CMSIS\Core\Include\cmsis_gcc.h 151                                     it is declared in file iccarm_builtin.h

Comment: I am not familiar with this IAR version, but it would seem odd that you'd use `cmsis_gcc.h` file. IAR is not GCC compiler. Perhaps you have chosen wrong cmsis version which is intended for gcc and not iar. (Also, please edit your error messages in to your question. They are hard to read on comments.)

Comment: I don't use IAR, but if no vectorization is enabled, Eigen should be fully C++03 compatible. Can you [edit] your question to include a [mre] of what you try to compile as well as the complete error you are getting?

Comment: Question has been edited. @chtz I disabled vectorization by using the EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE. I get the same errors though.

Comment: Can you check if the master branch of Eigen works (maybe in C++11 mode)? If you want your local version to work, you could try replacing the `#error` line by an empty macro `#define EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(n)` (or look up your compiler documentation what you need to write to statically align memory). Furthermore, you should compile with `EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN_STATICALLY` (or `EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN`).

Answer (score 1):

To add to @chtz answer, here's how I got the EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY macro to work with IAR, in a way that is consistent with the eigen library:

1: add this to top of Macros.h to identify the IAR ARM compiler

```
/// \internal EIGEN_COMP_ICCARM set to 1 if the compiler is IAR eWARM
#if defined(__ICCARM__)
    #define EIGEN_COMP_ICCARM 1
#else
    #define EIGEN_COMP_ICCARM 0
#endif
```

2: add this case to where EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(n) is defined in Macros.h

```
 #elif EIGEN_COMP_ICCARM
      #define IAR_STRINGIFY(a) #a
      #define IAR_ALIGN_STR(n) IAR_STRINGIFY(data_alignment=n)
      #define EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(n) _Pragma(IAR_ALIGN_STR(n))
```

EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(n) should now correctly expand to _Pragma("data_alignment=n")

Answer (score 0):

I have now gotten it to build and run. Thank you @chtz for the EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN macro suggestion. This is how I did it. I am unsure however what repercussions this has on the library itself, as in what features this may take away. I did this:

1. include the directory to where you installed Eigen as the additional includes.
2. in lines 86, 105, 125, 145  in file DenseStorage.h  change the lines 
   EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(8) T array[Size];
   to their respective
   _Pragma("data_alignment=8") T array[Size];
   (pay attention to the number)
3. in Macros.h , line 665 , comment out the "#error Please tell me what is the"
4. finally, define the macro EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN in the preprocessor settings.

This is what worked for Eigen 3.3.7

Comment: Looks like `#define EIGEN_ALIGN_TO_BOUNDARY(n) _Pragma("data_alignment=" #n)` should work (ideally `#if`-guarded by a way which identifies your compiler). You should not need to modify DenseStorage.h, and probably you won't even need `EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN` then (and `EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE` might also have no effect in your case).